# Error:10061, 'No connection could be made' Browsermob-proxy

Tags: python, http, python-requests, robotframework, browsermob

I am using the browsermob-proxy to capture traffic from selenium tests. I was making the requests from inside of the robotframework and occasionally got the issue: Connection aborted: Error10061, No connection could be made because the target actively refused it. So I moved all of the requests into python using the requests library but now it consistantly fails on:

```
def saveHar(self, proxy, name):
    server, req = proxy
    name +=str(server.harCount) + ".har"
    print name
    print server, "    ", server.url
    har = req.put(server.url+"/proxy/11049/har")
    print har
    print har._content
```

req being a requests library session and server being the browsermob-proxy server. 
I am confused as to what is causing this error, I have tried closing the connection and allowing the port in the firewall but it still fails. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, added a check to make sure the server is listening before I send the request